# code blocks not running

Tags: codeblocks

I use ubuntu 12.1 64db,I installed code blocks but when I run a project "c project" it gives me "It seems that this project has not been built yet,Do you want to build it now?"
when I click yes it gives Linking console executable: bin/Debug/test /bin/sh: 1: g++: not found

so how can I run the project?

Comment: what do you mean by `run`? Like execute the program?

Comment: Build and run, execuitng

Comment: Then when it says to build it.. Build it, you can't run something that hasn't been built.

Comment: Okay, what happens when you build it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you want to execute your code. In that case, when you want to `run` it, you must first click yes to building the project. Since you must first compile and link your code into a final executable before it can be run.

Edit: He didn't have `g++` >.>

Install `g++` with `sudo apt-get install g++` and that should solve your issues.

Comment: I clicked yes but it gives the same question

Comment: When you clicked yes, does it actually build the project or give you some warnings?

Comment: Then it should run... Do you have some image?

Comment: @user1865719, okay, but what happens after you build it? What does it show then?

Comment: Linking console executable: bin/Debug/test
/bin/sh: 1: g++: not found

Comment: So you don't have g++? go in a terminal and type `g++ -v` what does it say?

Comment: thank very much it solved my problem it wasn't installed edit your answer to approve it thanks

Answer (score 0):

> --1. First of all **download MinGW** : https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/ [][1]

```
       [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJndz.png
```

> --2. Double click the **mingw-set-up.exe** and press **Install**. [][1]

```
       [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz5Jf.png
```

> --3. **Dont change** the Installation Directory and press **Cointinue**

```
      [1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/boOGj.png
```

> --4. **Wait** until installed...

```
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WCnJ.png
```

> --5. Then press **Continue and wait** again..

> --6. **Mark all files** for installation

```
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtq08.png
```

> --7. Go: **Intallation --> Apply Changes**. Press again **Apply** and **wait** the Download Package.

```
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNvtB.png
```

> --8. Press **"Close dialogue automatically,.."** and **wait**...

```
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/65efE.png
```

> --9.You can close MinGW.

> --10.Copy the addres of new MinGW bin file which should be C:\MinGW\bin

> --11.Right click on your **start** and press **System**

> --12. Press **Advanced system settings**--> **Environment variable**

```
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr2sL.png
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ1oK.png
```

> --13. In **System variables** click **Path** and then **Edit**.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pCEO.png
```

> --14. Then press **New** and paste the addres of file "bin" that is inside of file MinGW in Documents(step 10) that should be C:\MinGW\bin.Then press OK-->OK-->OK.

```
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQmFF.png
```

> --15. Open **cmd**.I mean Right click on your start and press Command Prompt.Write
> **g++ --version** and press enter. [If it is like this you dont have problem][1]

```
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a52LH.png
```

> --16. **Open Codeblocks** go **settings-->Compiler**. **Select**" GNU GCC Compiler ".

```
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU9pB.png
```

> --17. Go **Toolchain executales** and fill in the blanks as in the Screenshot .Files must be in local disk in C:\MinGW\bin chose from there.

CAUTION!!!! This SCREENSHOT IS FOR 32-BIT SYSTEMS. I am not sure for 64-Bit systems. [32-BIT SYSTEMS][1]

```
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JJh0.png
```

> --18. **If you have 64-Bit** **dont** do the 17st step and tried if it works .If it's not work do the 17st step.If it's not work again try to put files (to "C compiler", "c++ compiler" and to "linker for dynamics li") that have almost the same name as the files that are in screenshot.

Comment: Please reformat your answer. Note the screenshot link.